# Invalid `prisma.user.create()` invocation in

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, post, prisma

I am registering a user through a POST request and storing it in the database using the prism in Node, the request is working, but when it executes the prisma function to register the new user with the information coming from the POST, it generates this error in the console:

```
PrismaClientUnknownRequestError: 
Invalid `prisma.user.create()` invocation in
```

I did some tests with GET request and it was successful, so I think the problem is really in the function and its parameters, but I couldn't find anything divergent, here are some parts of the code for support, i'm using NodeJS with Typescript and PostgreSQL.

**schema.prisma**

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
    provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
    provider = "postgresql"
    url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
    id             Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
    name           String
    birthDate      String
    email          String @unique
    password       String
    cpf            String
    street         String
    numberStreet   String
    district       String
    city           String
    zipCode        String
    numberTel      String
    numberCel      String
}
```

registration function:

```
export class UserController {
  async store(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const {
      name,
      birthDate,
      email,
      password,
      cpf,
      street,
      numberStreet,
      district,
      city,
      zipCode,
      numberTel,
      numberCel,
    } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body)
    const user = await prisma.user.create({
      data: {
        name,
        birthDate,
        email,
        password,
        cpf,
        street,
        numberStreet,
        district,
        city,
        zipCode,
        numberTel,
        numberCel
      },
    });

    res.sendStatus(201);
    return res.json({user})
  }
}
```

POST request I'm using to perform the registration:

```
http://localhost:3333/NewUser

{
    "name": "Waguinho",
    "birthDate": "1992-02-12T11:24:59:3232",
    "email": "waguinho@gmail.com",
    "password": "123",
    "cpf": "1",
    "street": "1",
    "numberStreet": "1",
    "district": "1",
    "city": "1",
    "zipCode": "1",
    "numberTel": "1",
    "numberCel": "1"
}
```

Comment: It's not easy to pinpoint the exact issue here. Can you please add the complete error log?